# Extract the contents of heading tags (h1 to h6) using regex in java

Tags: java, html, regex, pattern-matching

I want to extract the contents of all heading tags from a web page.
I tried this regex

> `(?i)<h([1-6].*?)>(.*?)</h([1-6])>`

The problem is if head tag is like this-

> `<h1><I>Contents</I></h1>`

its giving me output -

> `<I>Contents</I>.`

I want it to print only

> Contents

in output.
How should I modify this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: use http://jsoup.org/ instead

Comment: @nikis I already done my remaining job  of project using regex.

Comment: @alice edited the answer, test it out

Answer (score 3):

```
(?<=\>)(?!\<)(.*)(?=\<)(?<!\>)
```

This is going to work even with the input being `<h1><I>Contents</I></h1>`. Test it out here: https://regex101.com/r/tF7tG7/1

---

### Explanation

Using lookaheads and lookbehinds, I always check if there is no more `>` character at the beginning of your capture group. Then I capture everything in between. Then, I check if there is no more `<` before the one I captured. Look into lookaheads and lookbehinds for a more clear understanding.

### Implemented in PHP

```
<?php
$string = "<h1><I>Contents</I></h1>";
preg_match("#(?<=\>)(?!\<)(.*)(?=\<)(?<!\>)#", $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

### WARNING

Please, for the love of god, do not use regular expressions to parse any form of HTML or XML.

## MAJOR EDIT

```
(?<=(?!h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6)\>)(?!\<)(.+?)(?=\<\/.+?(?=h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6))
```

This regular expression parses the content the way you want to. Test it out here: https://regex101.com/r/vM1rI0/1

Comment: The OP is looking for headings h1..h6. It looks like your regexp does not: it will match anything between things that look like html start and end tags.

Comment: it seems interesting. but it's matching contents between paragraph tag , title tags etc.. also.

Comment: @alice I'm sorry, I misread the question. Thought you wanted the content inside generally. I'll correct the answer once I'm home.

Comment: @jvitasek this code is working fine for "<h1><I>Contents</I></h1>". but not for "<h1>Contents</h1>". Please help me out.